# How to get windows laptop current location in C++ application using System.Device.Location namespace

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, geolocation, windows-10-sdk

I am trying to retrieve my windows laptop geo location from a C++ application.
The below link contain a beautiful example written in C++, but this only works if GPS sensor is present in laptop, and this COM API got deprecated and windows may stop the service itself anytime sooner.

https://www.winwaed.com/blog/2018/12/07/using-the-windows-7-location-api/

As per the windows, the most recent recommended way of getting GeoLocaiton is documented in below URL, but this needs a C# application to use the **System.Device.Location**  namespace, whereas I need a C++ solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/locationapi/windows-location-api-portal

System.Device.Location namespace uses wifi Access point as well to retrieve the location, therefore GPS chip dependency is no longer present.

Could anyone recommend on how can I use this System.Device.Location namespace in C++ application?

~Ashish

Comment: Create a wrapper in C++/CLI?

Comment: hello i have the same problem and i'm wondering if you found a way

Comment: Hi!! I am able to use the same link as shared above to get the geo location using C++ and WIN32 COM libraries. It  will not work for Win10 OS for sure, but I am able to get the location in Win8.1 OS. WIN8.1 OS has a driver inbuild called Windows Location Driver, which provides the geo location to the C++ client even if the GPS chip not present on the machine.    It uses the ip address, wifi signal to get the geo location.   https://www.winwaed.com/blog/2018/12/07/using-the-windows-7-location-api/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

Use C++ ATL COM to obtain real-time GPS coordinates on the Windows platform, support location monitoring, and implement the same method as dotNet's System.Device.Location

https://github.com/spianmo/GeoLocation